# Prove that each connected component of a surface is also a surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

**QUESTION:** Prove that each connected component of a surface is also a surface. (Hint: Connected components of a locally connected space are open.)

**Definition:** A space $X$ is said to be **locally connected at $x$** if for every neighborhood U of x, there is a connected neighborhood $V$ of $x$ contained in $U$.

**Theorem 1:** A space $X$ is locally connected if and only if for every open set $U$ of $X$, each component of $U$ is open in $X$.

**Theorem 2:** Every open subset in a surface is also a surface.

**MY ATTEMPT:** Let $x\in S$ be a connected component in the surface $S$, such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is a connected neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $x\in U$, i.e. $S$ is locally connected at $x$. Now, due $U$ is an open subset in $S$, let $C$ be a component of $U$, if $x\in C$ we can choose a connected neighborhood $v$ of $x$ such that $V\subset U$. Because $V$ is connected, it works for every $C\subset U$. Therefore $C$ is open in $S$.

**MY DOUBT:** Unfortunatelly my attempt is very similar to the proof of theorem 1 (in James Munkres). I just modified few things. My doubts are how can I garantee that always exists a connected neighborhood $V$ of $x$ (because I'm in $S$ wich is a surface) and if my proof provided is correct?

Comment: How are you defining surface? Do you know about charts? If so, then choose a pt. $x\in C$ a component of $X$. There is a homeomorphism $\varphi:  U\cap X \to V$ where $U$ is open in $\Bbb R^3$ and $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^2.$ Now note that $C$ is open and $\varphi$ restricted to $C$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Very nice. I realized right now that my doubt was exactly in the definition of Surface. Thanks very much.

Comment: However I would like to be more rigorous in my proof. Do you think if I add this explaining regarding with the definition of surface it might be better?

Comment: I think once you know how surfaces are defined through slice charts, and that components are open, my comment is a reasonable proof. Unless you want to show that the restriction of the homeomorphism $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. Or, what do you have in mind, maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, I found where I've made a mistake. I didn't get that components are open to be honest... But it is ok. You helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.